# Android - button clicks in tab view

Tags: android, button, tabs

I am very new to Android programming, but I've taken a fair amount of tutorials. But still, I am having problems with the following.

I took this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html. Besides, I took this tutorial for button clicks: developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

I have added a button and an EditText to the first tab layout. Just for testing purposes, I would like the EditText to become invisible if I press the button. Here is my code:

```
package test.HelloTabWidget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ArtistsActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText et;

    private OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            et.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.artists);

        et = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);        
    }
}
```

This code is for the first tab. I have actually tried to create a new project and just use standard layout, and then use the code above. Then it works perfectly. So I don't really understand why it won't work here.

**Update:** Works now, but I'm afraid that I have no idea what caused the error and why it is now working.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything inherently wrong with this. You can see the Button and the EditText fine in the tab layout? What does layout/artists.xml look like?

Comment: @Kevin, yeah they show up like they should. Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/4EgAbA9E

Comment: Looks alright to me. The only thing I can think to suggest at this point is to set a breakpoint in the `OnClickListener` and debug to just make *sure* it is actually getting called (don't see why it wouldn't though - I'm trying pretty much this exact code and it's working for me).

Comment: @Kevin, it seems I can't get my phone to go into debugging (and yes, it's set to developer mode); it shows some kind of short message when "waiting for debugger", and it has to force close. Anyway, I don't know if I should have said this in the first post, but the main activity of the app is mainly controlling the tabs. This activity, ArtistsActivity, is run if the 1st tab is chosen. Don't know if it has anything to say.

Comment: Yeah, I followed the 'HelloTabView' tutorial that you linked to, so I should have pretty much the same basic setup as far as TabHost and all that stuff. That is weird that the app force closes when in debug but not in normal mode...How does it perform in an emulator?

Comment: Either I don't know how to debug properly (never done it before in Eclipse), or something else is wrong. I get the same error as on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing. As stated in the bottom of the original post, the problem fixed itself mysteriously.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () { 

 public void onClick(View v) { 

 et.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

}

});

Inside your onCreate(). Really should be fine either way though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it's still not working I'm afraid.